# Next on same line as For with If statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 'functions' module where I keep a bunch of useful code that reduces coding time and redundancy. What i'd really like to do is sandwich the code as much as I can. The problem I'm having is that you cannot place a 'Next' instruction on the same line as a 'For' and 'if'.

Here's what I currently have (These are multi-use functions, so please forgive the variants :P):

```
Function GetArrCol(xArray As Variant, xHeaderName As Variant, xHeaderRow As Variant) As Variant
Dim jCol As Long
For jCol = LBound(xArray, 2) To UBound(xArray, 2): If xArray(xHeaderRow, jCol) = xHeaderName Then GetArrCol = jCol: Exit For
Next jCol
If GetArrCol = Empty Then GetArrCol = "Error: Column Header Not Found"
End Function
```

What I wish i could be:

```
Function GetArrCol(xArray As Variant, xHeaderName As Variant, xHeaderRow As Variant) As Variant
Dim jCol As Long
For jCol = LBound(xArray, 2) To UBound(xArray, 2): If xArray(xHeaderRow, jCol) = xHeaderName Then GetArrCol = jCol: Exit For: Next jCol
If GetArrCol = Empty Then GetArrCol = "Error: Column Header Not Found"
End Function
```

I don't really think it's possible, but worth the ask.

Comment: Why would you do this?  You are making the code hard to read and therefore hard to maintain.  Think about the next developer who comes along.

Comment: This is terrible practice for coding, and there is no need for it besides.  Please don't get in the habit of trying to put everything on a single line.

Comment: If someone on my team wrote code like that, I'd superglue his/her right pinky to the Enter key and keep feeding them double-espressos until they developed a nervous tick.

Comment: This is not for anyone else to read. this is my own personal code.

Comment: For those who question my practices, I also challenge you to question your own 'best practices' to see what's possible, and push the boundaries. There is no absolute need to format the code this way, but rather my own OCD for organization and simplification. Such code could also be easily expanded by copying to word and replacing ":" with ^p. Maybe there's a way to do this in the console too? Maybe something worth exploring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of *shrinking* code, but I must admit not to such an extent as you showed!

but your question and other people's comment led me to some thinking and I came up to the following

1. think of/search for the best solution of the specific problem

   any specific problem has many solutions, which may fit differently in different environments

   a fine question to ask yourself is: "is there any built in function" to take advantage of?
2. direct your shrinking efforts into writing small pieces of codes

   these are helper subs/functions that do a very specific work and do it fine

   and their maintenance is very simple and fast

   sort of building a class and exposing its methods and properties

   wait a moment: you could that, indeed !
3. design and maintain a class

   this will lead to a very high degree of flexibility and maintenance

   and, to a certain extent with VBA, to polymorphism

so taking a "normal" wording of your code:

```
Function GetArrCol(xArray As Variant, xHeaderName As Variant, xHeaderRow As Variant) As Variant
    Dim jCol As Long
    For jCol = LBound(xArray, 2) To UBound(xArray, 2)
        If xArray(xHeaderRow, jCol) = xHeaderName Then
            GetArrCol = jCol
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If GetArrCol = Empty Then GetArrCol = "Error: Column Header Not Found"
End Function
```

an example of point 1) would be:

there you see that `GetArrCol()` needs to loop through a certain 2D array row to find a text and return its column index

that means it has to:

- slice an array, and get one of its rows
- return the sliced row column index of a certain item (if any)

and here we have two sub-tasks to concentrate on:

- googling "VBA slice an array" will get you for sure to an `Application.Index()` function feature

  and so you'll use some `Application.Index(myArray, rowIndex, 0)` to get `myArray` row n° `rowIndex`
- googling "VBA search an array" will get you for sure to `Application.Match()` function

  and so you'll use some `Application.Match(myValue, myArray, 0)` to get the column index of `myvalue` item in `myArray` array, or an error
- combining the above two *discoveries* would results in:

  ```
  Function GetArrCol(xArray As Variant, xHeaderName As Variant, xHeaderRow As Variant) As Variant
      GetArrCol = Application.Match(xHeaderName, Application.index(xArray, xHeaderRow, 0), 0)
      If IsError(GetArrCol) Then GetArrCol = "Error: Column Header Not Found"
  End Function
  ```

  which, you must admit, is much shorter, clearer and maintainable then your *coloned* code

While an example of point 2, would be:

in your `GetArrCol()` function you have a the following code block inside a loop

```
    If xArray(xHeaderRow, jCol) = xHeaderName Then
        GetArrCol = jCol
        Exit For
    End If
```

which you may demand to another function as follows

```
    Function found(xArray As Variant, xHeaderName As Variant, xHeaderRow As Variant, jCol As Long, GetArrCol As Variant) As Boolean
        found = xArray(xHeaderRow, jCol) = xHeaderName
        If found Then GetArrCol = jCol
    End Function
```

and so your main function code would reduce to

```
    Function GetArrCol(xArray As Variant, xHeaderName As Variant, xHeaderRow As Variant) As Variant
        Dim jCol As Long
        For jCol = LBound(xArray, 2) To UBound(xArray, 2)
            If found(xArray, xHeaderName, xHeaderRow, jCol, GetArrCol) Then Exit For
        Next
        If GetArrCol = Empty Then GetArrCol = "Error: Column Header Not Found"
    End Function
```

Finally I really should enclose an example of a Class implementation.

But I really wrote too much so ... let's see if you want to face it!

Answer (score 0):

Changed for loop to Do:

```
Function GetArrCol2(xArray As Variant, xHeaderName As Variant, xHeaderRow As Variant) As Variant
Dim xTestVal As Variant: On Error Resume Next: GetArrCol2 = (LBound(xArray, 2) - 1): Do:: GetArrCol2 = (GetArrCol2 + 1): xTestVal = xArray(xHeaderRow, GetArrCol2): Loop Until xTestVal = xHeaderName Or (GetArrCol2 = UBound(xArray, 2) + 1): On Error GoTo 0
If GetArrCol2 = (UBound(xArray, 2) + 1) Then GetArrCol2 = "Error: Column Header Not Found"
End Function
```